# Log do Tomcat muito pesado

Tags: servidor, tomcat

Tenho notado que alguns arquivos que ficam dentro da pasta `Log` do `Tomcat` estão ficando pesados demais. Ontem deletei um arquivo com `40GB` e hoje já tem outro com `2GB`.

Eu não consigo ler o conteúdo desses arquivos pois são grandes demais.

- Como esses Logs são gerados? Será que meu sistema está mal
  configurado?
- Existe alguma maneira de desativar ou limitar o tamanho desses
  arquivos?

Esse é o arquivo que está com 2GB no momento: `tomcat8-stdout`.

Comment: Qual o level setado para os logs no conf/logging.properties ?

Comment: O level para algumas propriedades é `INFO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há várias possíveis razões, que geralmente se misturam. As mais comuns são:

- Níveis de log independentes. Pode ser que o log geral esteja `INFO`, mas para algumas classes ou aplicações esteja diferente. Verifique configurações de log no tomcat e também nas aplicações que estão executando.
- Escrevendo para mais de um lugar. As aplicações podem estar redirecionando os logs para o `stdout` ao invés de arquivos individuais, ou quem sabe até para os dois lugares.
- Aplicações escrevendo diretamente no `stdout`. Sistemas mal feitos ou com programadores desatentos podem ter no código alguns `System.out.println` e `e.printStackTrace` que foi deixado lá para depuração durante o desenvolvimento, mas que agora não tem como ser desligado. Para piorar, as vezes colocam isso dentro de laços.
- Muitas aplicações executando no mesmo servidor. Quanto mais sistemas, mais logs. Entretanto, eles deveriam escrever para diferentes arquivos.
- Muitos acessos ao servidor. Quanto mais acessos, mais logs. Verifique se não houve um pico de acesso ou se o número de usuários não está acima da capacidade do servidor.

### Considerações

Pelo tamanho do arquivo, eu diria que existem algumas classe logando com `DEBUG` ou `TRACE` ou que todas as consultas ao banco de dados estão estão escritas.

Inevitavelmente você vai precisar olhar o logs para entender o que está ocorrendo. Claro que não vai ser possível usar um editor de texto tradicional, então use uma outra ferramenta para carregar o arquivo parcialmente ou para extrair parte do arquivo para outro. Se você usar Linux ou Mac vai ser fácil, se for com Windows vai penar um pouco, mas é possível.

Finalmente, **configure log rotativo** especificando um tamanho máximo para o arquivo. Assim você evita muita dor de cabeça e ainda pode arquivar os logs de forma rotineira. Somente cuidado ao descartar logs antigos muito cedo, você pode precisar deles para auditoria, detectar fraudes ou investigar bugs obscuros.

Comment: Lembrando que nem precisa descartar os rotativos, pode compactar no servidor, e mover periodicamente para um arquivo local, desocupando o servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu acho que eu sei o que está acontecendo, esqueci ligada a propriedade do Hibernate que printa o código do SQL a cada operação. Vou desabilitar essa propriedade.

Comment: @Techies faz todo sentido. Tomara que seja só isso.